# Spotlight always asking if it should reopen already opened xls file

Tags: macos, ms-office, spotlight

I am a fan of Spotlight and always tend to use it for navigating through my opened apps and docs. However I found out, that when it comes to xls files that are already opened, I get a popup with a message asking me to confirm if I would like to reopen a file or use an existing one. It looks like: "filename.xls is already open. Reopening will cause any changes you made to be discarded...".

I wonder is there a way to skip getting the popup message and just focus to an already opened xls window?

I am using Yosemite
Microsoft Office Excel 2011 14.2 version

Comment: That doesn't sound like Spotlight—it might be just Excel. If you double-click the file in Finder while Excel is still open, do you get the popup?

Comment: Yep, it is caused by Excel itself. Still didn't manage to find a solution how to force Excel not to reopen already opened file.